# weird bit character display

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing x and y as bits in mysql database, upon fetch the record using php fetch_assoc, the display is gobbled.  And I can't find a way to test the value to see if it's true or false... I tried using if($val), if($val==true) if($val===true), if $val is false, all 3 tests still returns true.  any idea?
[x] => � [y] =>

thanks for the answer below, I now use:

```
function mysql_bit($bit) {

    if(ord($bit) == 0 || ord($bit) == 48)return false;
    return true;
}
```

to handle both mysql bit value and regular string/int value(from http request for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this post help?

- http://jameslow.com/2008/08/12/mysql-bit-in-php/

I had this issue a looooong time ago... it is read as an ascii '1' or '0'.  I don't think my solution at the time was exactly as nice, but I don't have the source anymore so I will pretend it was!

```
function mysql_bit($bit) {
    return ord($bit) == 1 || $bit == 1;
}
```

Comment: Kinda sad actually... had I used php in the last 3 years I would have remembered this and not had to crib from someone else ;)  If it works, mark it the solution so others know.

Comment: oops I said that too soon, it works fine when testing the value I get from the database.  The trouble is that in my php page I also get the value from $_REQUEST['variable'], when it is 1 (eg. test.php?test=1), mysql_bit returns false!!  any solution?

Comment: return ord($bit)==1 || $bit==1;

Comment: Mike: i guess that 'll work too, I have a version (see Edit) that works biased toward true

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, searched SO, and came across this post...

Which, in turn, led me to [this section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-values.html) in the mysql manual.

You need to do something like this when setting bit values:

```
update `t` set `bitfield`=b'0' where ...
```

That tells mysql that '0' is the bit value rather than the character 0.

Likewise, reading it gives binary data rather than the characters 0 or 1, but you can typecast it:

```
select cast(`bitfield` as unsigned) from `t` where ...
```

Or we can all just go back to using `tinyint(1)`...